# Degree of the Kummer extension - computing

Tags: number-theory, kummer-theory

I have a question.

I want to calculate the degree of the Kummer extension.

$D_{g}(k) = (\mathbb Q(g^{1/k}, e^{2\pi i /k}) : \mathbb Q)$

[Page 3 in [this](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/arnoldfinal.pdf) publication]

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What is $g$? $\,\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the degree of the splitting field of the polynomial $X^k-g$. The degree has been computed in general, see the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx), namely $\frac{\phi(k)k}{2^s}$.

Comment: Why $2^s$ ? It depends if $g^{p/k} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_k)$ for each $p | k$, right ?

Comment: Yes, the $s$ is as defined as in my other answer.