# A question regarding finding the minimal polynomial associated with a field extension .

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Say we have the field extension $\Bbb Q(w,\sqrt[3]{5})$ over $\Bbb Q$, where w is the primitive cubed root of unity.
I know that the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5}$ is $x^3-5$.
I want to figure out the degree of the extension;

I know we can use the tower law $|\Bbb Q(w, \sqrt[3]{5});\Bbb Q|=|\Bbb Q(w, \sqrt[3]{5});\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5})||\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5});\Bbb Q|=x.3$ as $x^3-5$ has degree 3

But how does one find the minimum polynomial of the extension  of degree x

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx) with $n=3$. So $x=2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I edited my question to hone in the part of the question I was particularly interested in , I'm not sure the duplicate link properly addresses that point

Comment: The duplicate has an answer exaxctly to this, i.e., why the first extension has degree $x=2$. That's your question, right?

Comment: $w$ is a root of $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. Since it is a primitive root (hence not equal to $1$) it isn't a root of $x-1$, so it is a root of $x^2+x+1$. This is a polynomial of degree $2$ which has no real roots, hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[3]{5})}$. So this is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: not quite, as an answer below stated $x^2+x+1$ is the minimum polynomial of the extension but I don't understand how this is found, maybe I'm not understanding something in the link but it didn't seem to show clearly how its assumed that this Is the minimum polynomial

Comment: @Mark ah okay that makes sense, thank you. One question though, how does one figure out the first factorisation you made in your comment ?

Comment: Well, this is a very known factorization. For a general $n$ we have $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1)$.

Comment: @Mark ah okay, I was sick for a lot of rings and fields last year  so I missed a lot of the more basic elements. So it's just a  general fact we can use, got ya ! thanks :)

Comment: Check the edited text for the way to get cube (or other) roots in your text (\sqrt[3] is what you need)

Answer (score -1):

Clearly $w \not \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{5})$ so the degree is at least $2$. Now notice that $x^2+x+1$ is the minimum polynomial.

Comment: Why is $x^2+x+1$ the minimum polynomial , how was it found ?

Comment: By noticing that $0=w^3-1=(w-1)(w^2+w+1)$.

Comment: An interesting generalisation of this problem could be this one: find the degree of the splitting field of $x^p-s$ over $\Bbb Q$ where $p$ is a prime number and $s>1$ is a squarefree integer.