# Simple extension finder for $x^p-2$

Tags: extension-field, galois-extensions

I believe that over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, the splitting field of the polynomial $x^p-2$ is finite and separable, and so it must also be simple. However, I am unable to find, for a general $p$, what the element of the simple extension must be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splitting field is $L=\Bbb Q(\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{2})$. A primitive element for the extension $L\mid \Bbb Q$ is $\alpha=\zeta_p+\sqrt[p]{2}$. 
We have $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=p(p-1)$, which is also the degree of $[L:\Bbb Q]$.

Comment: Assuming $p$ was meant to be prime in the problem. More generally, $[L:\mathbb Q]\leq p\cdot\phi(p).$ With $p=8$ then $\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb Q[\zeta_8]$ and then $L:Q]=4\cdot 4=16<8\cdot\phi(8).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, you are right. I was assuming that $p$ is prime.  We had discussed the general case for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx).