# Intersection of two extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

The original question is to find the Galois extension of the polynomial $x^9-5$. There are multiple questions before the actual question. Assuming $F$ = $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive 9th root of unity and $L$ = $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is the real root of $x^9-5$. I have proved that the only non-trivial subextension of $L$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma^3)$. I am unable to prove whether $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma^3)$ is equal to $\mathbb{Q}(cos(2\pi/9))$ (which is subextesion of $F$ ) or not. If yes then $F$ intersection $L$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\gamma^3)$ otherwise it is $\mathbb{Q}$. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you need the intersection of these to find the splitting field? The splitting field is their composition, not their intersection.

Comment: For the Galois group of $x^n-a$ and intersection see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx). So the Galois group is $\Bbb Z/9\rtimes (\Bbb Z/9)^{\times}$ of order $9\cdot \phi(9)=54$.

Comment: This $\gamma$ is usually denoted by $\sqrt[9]{5}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for sharing the link and for the answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so the intersection will precisely be $\mathbb{Q}$ right? just clarifying

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is just $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}(\gamma^3)$ is not a Galois extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ but $\Bbb{Q}(2\cos(2\pi/9)$ is.